# NHibernate -- How to fake one side of a many-to-many normalization

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following two tables:

```
Package
id

ClientPackage
id
clientNumber
packageId
```

The thing is that I do not have a Client table in this database (it resides in another database).  Is there a way that I can create a Client mapping to a Client model which just consist of distinct "clientNumber" from the ClientPackage table while treating ClientPackage as a association table -- meaning that I do not want a class or mapping for ClientPackage.  I'm thinking that I could use a component and an idbag to accomplish this but I just wanted a more experienced opinion so that I know I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From NH's perspective, this is not a many-to-many relationship, precisely because Client is not mapped.

The mapping depends on how you want it represented in the domain model.

An idbag would work fine for mapping `Package.Clients` as an `ICollection<int>`. You don't need a component:

```
<idbag name="Clients" table="ClientPackage">
  <collection-id column="id" type="...">
    <generator class="..."/>
  </collection-id>
  <key column="packageId"/>
  <element column="clientNumber"/>
</idbag>
```

And then you'll use those ids to get the clients in the other database.